# Is there a way to extend BlogEngine in order to prevent unauthenticated users from accessing images?

Tags: blogengine.net

Still using a very old (and slightly customized) version of BlogEngine.NET on a Windows XP (!) server so I'm a bit afraid to upgrade.

In the past, I have written a couple of extensions in order to grant or prevent access to static pages and/or posts based upon the users / roles and / or the post categories. For instance, I can prevent access to the blog from unauthenticated users, I can grant access to a subset of the blog (post categories) to users having the 'Readers' role, etc.

I noticed that images are still accessible, either ones stored explicitly under the /App_Data/files/ folder and served by the image.axd handler, or ones associated with blog posts.

Is there an extension point available where I could add some logic to prevent access to images based on criteria such as authentication and/or users / roles ? Perhaps based upon their file extensions, or whatnot ?

Comment: What is the old version you are using?

Comment: I'm using an old 2.0 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about an official extension point but I think the edits you need to make are as follows.

According to this line in the web.config

```
<add verb="*" path="image.axd" type="BlogEngine.Core.Web.HttpHandlers.ImageHandler, BlogEngine.Core" validate="false"/>
```

The `image.axd` is handled by `BlogEngine.Core.Web.HttpHandlers.ImageHandler`

If you look in the BlogEngine.Core project you will find the ImageHandler.cs that defines this class.  Assuming you need access to the Session you will need to `IReadOnlySessionState` as an implemented interface to the class.

```
public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState {
    ...
}
```

Once this is in place you can access the Session in the `ProcessRequest` Method to perform your custom checks.

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
    if(context.Session["SomeKey"] == true){
        //serve image code goes here
    }
}
```